# Save changes failing, but no exception thrown

Tags: c#, exception, savechanges

I have a case where I am calling SaveChanges, it is failing, throwing out of the try block, but not being caught. I have never heard of this happening, and your help would be appreciated.

I am using C# in Visual Studio 2008, with .net framework 3.5SP1.

The code in question is:

```
try
{
    using (EntityConnection conn = new EntityConnection(_connName))
    {
        MWDPLCEntities contxt = new MWDPLCEntities(conn);

        plcstatusmessage psmn = plcstatusmessage.CreatePLCStatusMessage(plcID, smID);
        contxt.AddToplcstatusmessage(psmn);
        contxt.SaveChanges();
    }
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
    LogService.addLog(ex.ToString(), LogService.LOG_EXCEPTION) ;
}
```

I have placed log statements before and after the SaveChanges line, and the one directly following does not get printed. However, the Exception does not get logged either, nor does the data get saved.

I am honestly puzzled as to how the error is happening without throwing an exception. I can only think that there is some other way that C# is reporting the error that I am not 'catching'.

If anyone has a pointer or suggestion, I would greatly appreciate it.

Bruce.

Comment: What happens if you remove the try/catch block? Does the application crash? Is this winforms? Webforms?

Comment: This can happen with exceptions that are very difficult to recover from (e.g., `StackOverflowException`). It's possible that the actual cause for the error is a p/Invoke stack imbalance elsewhere in the app.

Comment: This is a windows desktop app, using System.Windows.Forms.Form.

Comment: I removed the try/catch blocks, all the way up the line, and finally got an exception. Wohho.

Comment: Perhaps `LogService.addLog` is also silently failing?

Comment: It is an UpdateException. I have no idea why this was not caught at the source line.

Comment: Hmm. My LogService also logs the errors to the db. Perhaps this exception was caught, but because there was an UpdateException, it also could not write to the db?  I am reaching here.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. Tuzo, you were correct in that the LogService was swallowing the exception as well. Thanks to you all for your help.